# how to use indicator of oracle to postgresql using libpqxx

Tags: postgresql, null, libpqxx

Here's my code:

```
stmt=INSERT INTO tablename values(:dbname:dbnameInd);
EXEC SQL PREPARE preparestatement FROM :stmnt;
EXEC SQL EXECUTE preparestatement using dbname INDICATOR :dbnameInd
```

indicators are used retrieve null values from the database.I have to do same functionality for the postgresql using libpqxx interface.In the above code if the dbname is null dbnameInd will be -1 by using INDICATOR.I am not finding 
any such function in libpqxx.can you please help on this

Comment: Do you want to use embedded SQL (ECPG) or an object oriented database interface (libpqxx)?

Comment: I am going to use object oriented database interface libpqxx

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe can you please help me on this?

Comment: Your problem description is too unclear. You'd have to edit the question and make clear what you need.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am migrating oracle proc  code to postgresql code by using  libpqxx interface.so  I am not getting how can i achieve the same Indicator functionality  in the libpqxx.

Comment: With an object oriented approach (which libpqxx seems to take), I would expect an `isNull()` method or something similar in the C++ classes returned by a query

Comment: But the syntax you present is embedded SQL. Is the code you show from the Oracle program? If yes, do **not** use libpqxx, but use ECPG.

Comment: yes.The above one is Oracle program.we did some analysis  about  ibpqxx and ecpg. We decided that libpqxx is better compared to ECPG.So we are using libpqxx